# Write a single textfile multiple times with to_csv and write methods

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large python program with many process of pandas dataframes. At the end of each processes i need to write the output to a text file. So during the whole program the text file has to be updated with "to_csv" and "write" methods. Following are some of the lines that I use to write the text file. The problem is text file is overwritten with the lines of last process in the program. I want to write the text file multiple times during the program.

```
out = open('results.txt','a')

out.write( 'Message' )
out.write( head.idxmax())
df.sort(columns='Requests',  ascending=False).to_csv('results', sep=' ' )
```

If you need more explanations please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `mode` argument to [`.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv).

```
In [5]: df = DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar'],
                'B': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'two'],
                'C': np.random.randn(5)})


In [6]: with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    ...:     f.write('Testing\n')
    ...:     


In [7]: !cat 'test.txt'
Testing


In [11]: df.to_csv('test.txt', mode='a')

In [12]: !cat 'test.txt'
Testing
,A,B,C
0,foo,one,0.42364430570326805
1,foo,two,1.1992467813307852
2,foo,three,0.4302171615562164
3,bar,one,0.6837252733791036
4,bar,two,0.16800783901724345
```

Comment: I just tested it and it worked fine.  Make sure that you are writing the first changes.  Use a context manager.  with open('results.txt', 'a') as f: f.write('Hello'); df.to_csv('results.txt', mode='a')

Comment: Thanks Very Much Tom! It worked..:) Sorry for the previous comment!